# How to continuously rotate children in a jQuery animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a div with class 'bannergroup' that contains multiple divs 'banneritem'.  I want these items to rotate (fade in then fade out) in place of each other.

I can have several divs with the class bannergroup and each one should rotate separately.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="bannergroup">
  <div class="banneritem">Only visible one at a time</div>
  <div class="banneritem">Only visible one at a time</div>
  <div class="banneritem">Only visible one at a time</div>
  <div class="banneritem">Only visible one at a time</div>
</div>

<div class="bannergroup">
  <div class="banneritem">Only visible one at a time</div>
  <div class="banneritem">Only visible one at a time</div>
  <div class="banneritem">Only visible one at a time</div>
  <div class="banneritem">Only visible one at a time</div>
</div>
```

My Jquery looks like:

```
$('.banneritem').css('display', 'none');
$('.bannergroup').children('.banneritem').each(function( i ) {
  $(this).fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut();               
});
```

The problem:  the each statement continues to run before the previous div completes.  I want it to wait until the previous child is gone.  Also, I need this to continuously run.  After a single time it stops.  I can put this into a function, but I am not sure how to know to call it again.

*EDIT*:  There are not always 4 child items.  Also one group may have a different number of children than the others, but they should both rotate in-sync.  It is ok if one completes before the other and then just restarts itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have answered this question [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14474778/417685) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11100098/417685) before. This time I will try wrapping it in a jQuery plugin. The `.rotate()` function will apply the effect you want to the children of the matched elements, a fade in/out effect per children in a continuous animation.

```
$.fn.rotate = function(){
  return this.each(function() {

    /* Cache element's children */
    var $children = $(this).children();

    /* Current element to display */
    var position = -1;

    /* IIFE */
    !function loop() {

        /* Get next element's position.
         * Restarting from first children after the last one.
         */
        position = (position + 1) % $children.length;

        /* Fade element */
        $children.eq(position).fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, loop);
    }();
  });
};
```

Usage:

```
$(function(){
  $(".banneritem").hide();
  $(".bannergroup").rotate();
});
```

[See it here.](http://jsbin.com/usebef/2/edit)

Comment: Awesome- worked perfectly!  Sorry I could not find your previous answers.  Thank You!

Comment: @Alexander I looked at further examples of your code as it peaked my interest in it being clever so I could glean some good bits. I do have one question though, you are declaring an anonymous function, then a named function with recursion within. Would it not be more efficient (but not terse) to name the recursive function outside the .each ?

Comment: You need a higher scope for the `position` variable. You will still need two functions I believe, and moving the named function out of the `.each()` will increase the complexity for those variables

Answer (score 1):

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ydxfQ/1/)**

```
$('div.bannergroup').each(function () {
    $('div.banneritem', this).not(':first').hide();
    var thisDiv = this;
    setInterval(function () {
        var idx = $('div.banneritem', thisDiv).index($('div.banneritem', thisDiv).filter(':visible'));
        $('div.banneritem:eq(' + idx + ')', thisDiv).fadeOut(function () {
            idx++;
            if (idx == ($('div.banneritem', thisDiv).length)) idx = 0;
            $('div.banneritem', thisDiv).eq(idx).fadeIn();
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: [I can see that it works](http://jsfiddle.net/wHzkH/). You may want to correct the wrong markup that you used to test it though :)

Comment: @j08691 Is it possible to change the the current one by clicking one a link? E.g. I have a navigation in which I want to have 4 buttons. These four buttons display my 4 banneritems. I click on Button 1 and it shows banneritem 1. Click on Button2 and it shows banneritem 2. After that it continues with the right, following banneritem.

Comment: @ShawnWhite - Sorry but I don't understand what you're asking. Can you create a new question with an example?

Comment: @j08691 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661245/rotating-child-elements-in-wrapper-button-navigation

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in 2 ways. The one below is the easiest, using the index to increase the delay per item.

```
$('.banneritem').css('display', 'none');
$('.bannergroup').children('.banneritem').each(function( i ) {
  $(this).delay(4000 * i)).fadeIn().delay(4000 * (i+1)).fadeOut();               
});
```

Comment: This fades them all in right away and then fades them out 1 by one.  I tried modifying it by adding delay(4000*(i-1) before the fade in, but the new one fades in before the other one has faded out.  the 4000 delay does not take into account the fadeIn/fadeOut time.