# Overflow: hidden is not working with images

Tags: html, css, image

What I want to do is to make the image overflow in the x-axis hidden (instead of the first blonde woman being on the second row I want her to be cropped as necessary but yet remain on the first row and so on). When I do overflow-x hidden it won't work. Any thoughts on this one?

```css
#portrait {
  height: 300px;
  width: 550px;
  border: solid;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  float: left;
  height: 30%;
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="portrait">
  <img class="image" src="http://media.indiatimes.in/media/photogallery/2012/Dec/best_images_of_2012_1355117665_1355117684.jpg" />
  <!--Can't pull all images in here because it thinks my question is spam-->
  <img class="image" src="http://adrao.com.sapo.pt/soajo_sol.jpg" />
  <img class="image" src="http://www.befrielsen1945.dk/temaer/internationalt/krigensgang/kilder/ofre.jpg" />
  <img class="image" src="http://ionenewsone.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/oj-simpson-smiling-murder-trial.jpg" />
  <img class="image" src="http://images.nymag.com/images/2/daily/2009/10/20091006_gossipgirl_560x375.jpg" />
  <img class="image" src="http://images.nymag.com/images/2/daily/2009/10/20091006_gossipgirl_560x375.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082527/display-certain-phrases-depending-on-left-right-buttons-content-slider-for-text/15133551#15133551) it might help you, You need to make your images float next to each other inside a containing div - here is the fiddle example [http://jsfiddle.net/2s95M](http://jsfiddle.net/2s95M/20/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j4Ad7/

Comment: Musa, is there any other way to do that but including "float:left"? Ty for you answer Wezly but it's exactly what Musa wrote that I'm searching for.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since #portrait is not allowed to overflow the images then
**you need one additional container** with the specified width that will hold these the images inside.
Do it like this:

```
<div id="portrait">
    <div id="wrapper">
        your images
...
```

And then apply

```
#wrapper{
    height:30%;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 1000px; /* it is only important to be bigger then parent for one image width size */
}

.image{
  height: 100%;
```

Comment: since you want images to float, but not to go into another line, you need something to hold them together, and this will be #wrapper, also the #wrapper will be bigger then portrait so overflow:hidden from #portrait will cut it nicely the way you need

Comment: awesome answer. you say that `#portrait is not allowed to overflow the images`,  please what do you mean by "not allowed"?

Comment: @Webwoman I just say by default it will not allow images to overflow meaning flow outside of its boundaries. It will break them into new lines

Comment: THANK YOU! THANK YOU! THANK YOU! THANK YOU! 

i've made my container 100% and animating and the images where not showing

made it XXXpx and boom!

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem where my video disappeared when I used overflow hidden. Turned out I needed to set the width of the container and not only the height.
And I didn't have to use any positioning on the container.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the overflow: hidden; property to the container and not the image. It will solve your problem!!