# CSS Image overflow hidden without stretch

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to reduce the thumbnail's height without stretching the image. Despite I wrote my code in React I know is pure CSS.

For example, I used a sample screenshot from Wikipedia, its height is too large to fit "in a thumbnail" so I need to reduce it so a JavaScript library can autoscroll it when hover event is triggered (but this is a future step).

The following image is how the thumbnail should look like:

[image]

Instead it displays the whole image, as you can see below:

```css
.image {
  width: 200px;
}

.image-link {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<a class="image-link" href="#">
  <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/openscreenshot/A%2FG%2FO/AsjRlWOGA.png" class="image" />
</a>
```

So, how can I reduce the image's height without stretching it or overflowing the `a`?

Comment: Did you try object-fit: cover ?

Comment: Sorted it for you :)

Comment: @funkysoul, yes, I have tried that. it did't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: block;` (or `inline-block`, depending on the situation) to the class of the `a` tag, otherwise it's an inline element on which your `height` setting (and with it the `overflow: hidden`) won't have any effect:

```css
.image {
  width: 200px;
}

.image-link {
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<a class="image-link" href="#">
  <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/openscreenshot/A%2FG%2FO/AsjRlWOGA.png" class="image" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer:
( [Overflow: hidden is not working with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295042/overflow-hidden-is-not-working-with-images/20295236) ).

You need to add a wrapper element with all scaled images contained as the thing that is affected by `overflow`.

The images can then be adjusted in relation to that wrapper class.

```css
.image {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-link {
  width: 400px;
  
  height:400px;
  background-color:red;
}
.imageScale{
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<a class="image-link" href="#">
  <div class="image">
  <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/openscreenshot/A%2FG%2FO/AsjRlWOGA.png" class="imageScale" />
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: The previous answer is more accurate I guess, more elements are not needed.

Comment: @Maramal my bad, I didn't see that they had still cut off some of the image!